# Trying to debug Android logcat crash logs for React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, adb, logcat

I have a React Native app that is trying to go to a url as so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View styleName="main-refer">
            <WebPage uri="https://stage.example.com/refer/example" title="Referral" text="" noLoad={true} onMessage={(message) => this.onMessage(message)} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

is just a wrapper around React Native Webview with some added niceties for my specific implementation.

My onMessage method is like so:

```
onMessage(message) {
    this.props.crossbrowserSave(message.nativeEvent.data);

    let body = {
        fingerprint: message.nativeEvent.data
    };
    let api = new API(this.props.gatheredTokens, this.props.analytics);
    api
        .post("registerFingerprint", {
            body: queryString.stringify(body)
        })
        .then(response => this.postMessage(response))
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert("Unable to register referral.")
        });
}
```

The entire process works in the simulator and on iOS just fine. However when I am trying to do it on my Android tablet, it crashes, and I can't figure out the reason why.

Here's the logs that surround the crash as far as I can tell:

```
02-13 12:19:44.722   863  2233 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.clearcut.debug.ClearcutDebugDumpService in 386260ms
02-13 12:19:44.808   606   606 I Zygote  : Process 16137 exited due to signal (9)
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: handleMessage(): msg.what=8
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): uid=10003
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): caller UID doesn't match user UID
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: handleMessage(): msg.what=8
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): uid=10038
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): caller UID doesn't match user UID
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: handleMessage(): msg.what=8
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): uid=10158
02-13 12:19:44.838  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): caller UID doesn't match user UID
02-13 12:19:44.839   863  1425 D LocationManagerService: provider request: passive ProviderRequest[ON interval=0 lowPowerMode=false]
02-13 12:19:44.842   863  2238 I LocationManagerService: remove fb48295
02-13 12:19:44.844   606   606 I Zygote  : Process 16059 exited due to signal (9)
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: handleMessage(): msg.what=8
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): uid=10149
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): caller UID doesn't match user UID
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: handleMessage(): msg.what=8
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): uid=10123
02-13 12:19:44.847  1434  1434 D HidDeviceService: unregisterAppUid(): caller UID doesn't match user UID
02-13 12:19:44.856  1454  1454 D SamsungAnalytics201007: [DLC Sender] Client ServiceDisconnected
02-13 12:19:44.876   863  2238 D LocationManagerService: provider request: passive ProviderRequest[ON interval=0 lowPowerMode=false]
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10003
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10003 disabled=0
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10003
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10038 disabled=0
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10038
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10158
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10158 disabled=0
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10158
02-13 12:19:44.887   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10149
02-13 12:19:44.888   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10149 disabled=0
02-13 12:19:44.888   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10149
02-13 12:19:44.888   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10123
02-13 12:19:44.888   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: No processes running for a uid=10123 disabled=0
02-13 12:19:44.888   658  8608 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidIdle, uid = 10123
02-13 12:19:44.938  1434  1813 D BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - id: 7
02-13 12:19:44.943  1434  1813 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 7
02-13 12:19:44.949   863  1102 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 785ms so far, now at startProcess: returned from zygote!
02-13 12:19:44.951 16562 16562 E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
02-13 12:19:44.955   606   606 I Zygote  : Process 15278 exited due to signal (9)
02-13 12:19:44.959  1454  1454 D OverviewProxyService: internalConnectToCurrentUser : mPluginConnected=false
02-13 12:19:44.960  1454  1454 D OverviewProxyService: disconnectFromLauncherService : mOverviewProxy=true, mPluginConnected=false
02-13 12:19:44.973   606   606 I Zygote  : Process 15311 exited due to signal (9)
02-13 12:19:44.977 16562 16562 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 1
02-13 12:19:44.977  1454  1936 D TileLifecycleManager: binderDeath
02-13 12:19:44.977  1454  1936 D TileLifecycleManager: handleDeath
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService: Session failed to close due to remote exception
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService: android.os.DeadObjectException
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1145)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:339)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:3231)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:3222)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:3248)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:3276)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1868)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1883)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:812)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:633)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
02-13 12:19:45.012   863   863 W InputMethodManagerService:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
02-13 12:19:45.018   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: isImeSwitcherDisabledPackage : false
02-13 12:19:45.019   863  1307 D WifiStateMachine: enter getWifiLinkLayerStats
02-13 12:19:45.019   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: mDesktopModeManager null!
02-13 12:19:45.020   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: updateSystemUiLocked 0
02-13 12:19:45.020   863  1641 I ActivityManager: Process com.sec.spp.push:RemoteDlcProcess (pid 16059) has died: vis  IMPF(467,68)
02-13 12:19:45.022   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-16059, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 12:19:45.022   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10040 pid 16059 in 0ms
02-13 12:19:45.023   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: updateSystemUiLocked(), setImeWindowStatusToType, vis : 0 backDisposition : 0
02-13 12:19:45.024   863  1641 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.spp.push/.dlc.writer.WriterService in 395959ms
02-13 12:19:45.030   863   863 D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=387
02-13 12:19:45.041   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: isImeSwitcherDisabledPackage : false
02-13 12:19:45.041   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: mDesktopModeManager null!
02-13 12:19:45.041   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: updateSystemUiLocked 0
02-13 12:19:45.041   863   863 D InputMethodManagerService: updateSystemUiLocked(), setImeWindowStatusToType, vis : 0 backDisposition : 0
02-13 12:19:45.043   863  1102 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 879ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating battery stats
02-13 12:19:45.045   863  1101 W Looper  : Slow dispatch took 458ms android.ui h=com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler c=null m=53
02-13 12:19:45.045   863   863 W Looper  : Slow dispatch took 459ms main h=android.app.ActivityThread$H c=android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection@ef6658c m=0
02-13 12:19:45.046   863  1102 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 882ms so far, now at startProcess: building log message
02-13 12:19:45.046   863  1102 I ActivityManager: Start proc 16562:android:drmService/1000 for service android/com.android.server.DrmEventService
02-13 12:19:45.046   863  1102 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 882ms so far, now at startProcess: starting to update pids map
02-13 12:19:45.046   863  1102 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 882ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating pids map
02-13 12:19:45.046   863  2280 I ActivityManager: Process com.sec.android.app.launcher (pid 15278) has died: vis  IMPF(484,71)
02-13 12:19:45.047   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-15278, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 12:19:45.047   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10064 pid 15278 in 0ms
02-13 12:19:45.047   863   863 W Looper  : Slow system_server main looper dispatch took 459ms  h=android.app.ActivityThread$H
02-13 12:19:45.048   863  2280 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.quickstep.TouchInteractionService in 405935ms
02-13 12:19:45.049   863   863 D NetworkScoreService: ScoringServiceConnection, disconnected: com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.chimera.PersistentBoundBrokerService
02-13 12:19:45.061   863  2233 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=89, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10371] ], android.os.BinderProxy@82214d5)
02-13 12:19:45.061   863 13546 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=90, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND Unwanted:  Uid: 10371] ], android.os.BinderProxy@a99f4ea)
02-13 12:19:45.062   863  2236 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=92, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND Unwanted:  Uid: 10371] ], android.os.BinderProxy@328c3db)
02-13 12:19:45.062   863  1321 D ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=89, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10371] ] (release request)
02-13 12:19:45.063   863  1677 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=91, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10371] ], android.os.BinderProxy@a6a4e78)
02-13 12:19:45.064   863  6397 I ActivityManager: Process com.samsung.android.lool (pid 15311) has died: vis  BFGS(485,72)
02-13 12:19:45.065   863  6397 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.samsung.android.lool/com.samsung.android.sm.battery.ui.mode.BatteryModeTile in 415918ms
02-13 12:19:45.067   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-15311, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 12:19:45.067   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 15311 in 2ms
02-13 12:19:45.072   863  1270 W InputDispatcher: channel '287453 com.example_androidrn/com.example_androidrn.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=386
02-13 12:19:45.072   863  1270 E InputDispatcher: channel '287453 com.example_androidrn/com.example_androidrn.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-13 12:19:45.074   863  1321 D ConnectivityService:  Removing from current network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 602], leaving 15 requests.
02-13 12:19:45.081   863  6721 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{287453 u0 com.example_androidrn/com.example_androidrn.MainActivity}
02-13 12:19:45.084 16562 16562 E android:drmSer: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
02-13 12:19:45.092   451   451 I SurfaceFlinger: SFWD update time=434783472645
02-13 12:19:45.093   863  1307 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3140) before calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
02-13 12:19:45.093   863  6721 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '287453 com.example_androidrn/com.example_androidrn.MainActivity (server)'
```

I can't make heads or tails of the logs - it seems like it might be due to a difference between UIDs? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

EDIT - including more logs:

```
02-13 20:41:22.312  1434  1816 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.samsung.android.oneconnect, scannerId: 6, reportDelayMillis=0
02-13 20:41:22.331   863  1099 D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : 3
02-13 20:41:22.332   863  1099 D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : 3
02-13 20:41:22.332   863  1099 D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=3, uid : 10024, packageName : com.google.android.gms
02-13 20:41:22.335   863  1099 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.google.android.gms user:0
02-13 20:41:22.336   863  1099 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
02-13 20:41:22.336   863  1099 D ActivityManager: package  com.google.android.gms, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
02-13 20:41:22.336   863  1099 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.google.android.gms user:0
02-13 20:41:22.337   863  1099 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
02-13 20:41:22.337   863  1099 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.google.android.gms user:0
02-13 20:41:22.337   863  1099 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
02-13 20:41:22.338   446   446 E lmkd    : Error opening /proc/20344/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager: Exception when unbinding service com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.quickstep.TouchInteractionService
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1145)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleUnbindService(IApplicationThread.java:1172)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.removeConnectionLocked(ActiveServices.java:3098)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.unbindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:1887)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.unbindService(ActivityManagerService.java:25418)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:373)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4233)
02-13 20:41:22.347   863  2238 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
02-13 20:41:22.352   863 10383 I ActivityManager: Process com.sec.location.nsflp2 (pid 22148) has died: vis  BFGS(1167,109)
02-13 20:41:22.348   446   446 E lmkd    : Error opening /proc/20344/oom_score_adj; errno=2
02-13 20:41:22.352   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-22148, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.352   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 5013 pid 22148 in 0ms
02-13 20:41:22.353   863 10383 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.location.nsflp2/.nsmonitor.NSLocationManager in 336085ms
02-13 20:41:22.354   863 10383 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.location.nsflp2/.nsmonitor.NSMonitorService in 346084ms
02-13 20:41:22.363   863 10101 I ActivityManager: Process com.sec.spp.push:RemoteDlcProcess (pid 20827) has died: vis  IMPF(1179,110)
02-13 20:41:22.364   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-20827, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.364   863 10101 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.spp.push/.dlc.writer.WriterService in 356074ms
02-13 20:41:22.372   863  2236 I ActivityManager: Process com.teslacoilsw.launcher (pid 20337) has died: home HOME(1206,111)
02-13 20:41:22.372  1434  1813 D BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
02-13 20:41:22.373  1434  1813 D BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
02-13 20:41:22.373   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10040 pid 20827 in 9ms
02-13 20:41:22.374   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-20337, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.374   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10158 pid 20337 in 0ms
02-13 20:41:22.379  1434  1813 D BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - id: 8
02-13 20:41:22.379  1434  1813 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 8
02-13 20:41:22.383   863  7861 I ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.ext.services (pid 22276) has died: vis  BFGS(1225,111)
02-13 20:41:22.384   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-22276, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.384   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10025 pid 22276 in 0ms
02-13 20:41:22.384   863  7861 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.ext.services/android.ext.services.notification.Assistant in 366053ms
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  2236 D PowerManagerService: [api] setMasterBrightnessLimit : minBrightnss : -1  maxBrightness : 413 (uid: 1000 pid: 2226)
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  2236 D PowerManagerService: mDisplayReady: false
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  1115 D DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=-1
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  1115 D DisplayPowerController: getFinalBrightness : Summary is 98 -> 98
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  1115 D PowerManagerService: DisplayPowerCallbacks : onStateChanged()
02-13 20:41:22.387   863  1115 D PowerManagerService: mDisplayReady: true
02-13 20:41:22.391   863  2233 I ActivityManager: Process com.samsung.android.lool (pid 20362) has died: vis  BFGS(1231,112)
02-13 20:41:22.392   863  2233 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.samsung.android.lool/com.samsung.android.sm.battery.ui.mode.BatteryModeTile in 376046ms
02-13 20:41:22.396   863  1425 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 (pid 24350) has died: fore TOP (1260,112)
02-13 20:41:22.396   863  1425 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example_androidrn/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0 in 386041ms
02-13 20:41:22.391   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-20362, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.397   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 20362 in 5ms
02-13 20:41:22.397   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: Failed to open process cgroup uid 99079 pid 24350: No such file or directory
02-13 20:41:22.397   863  1103 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99079 pid 24350: No such file or directory
02-13 20:41:22.420   606   606 I Zygote  : Process 24001 exited due to signal (9)
02-13 20:41:22.460   863  1680 I ActivityManager: Process com.example_androidrn (pid 24001) has died: fore TOP (1291,104)
02-13 20:41:22.460   863  1103 W libprocessgroup: kill(-24001, 9) failed: No such process
02-13 20:41:22.461   863  1103 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10379 pid 24001 in 0ms
02-13 20:41:22.464   863  1680 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{b22685d u0 com.example_androidrn/.MainActivity t145}: app died, no saved state
```

Or possibly this part:

```
2020-02-13 21:16:32.729 863-1099/? E/PackageManager: Optimistic bind failed.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: [Optimistic Bind] Didn't bind to resolver in time!
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.waitForBindLocked(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:160)
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.bind(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:225)
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.lambda$optimisticBind$0(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:255)
        at com.android.server.pm.-$$Lambda$InstantAppResolverConnection$D-JKXi4qrYjnPQMOwj8UtfZenps.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

And this:

```
W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example_androidrn/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0 in 358896ms
```

Comment: this log does not contain the crash report, what does the screen of the app show? usually in react the crash is displayed white on red on the screen on the entire screen

Comment: The entire app just crashes straight to Android. No indication about what’s causing it at all. Can’t replicate in the simulator, only on device

Comment: in the logcat scroll through the processes running there might be a "dead" process there, its the 2nd dropdown at the top of the logcat window, if you switch to that, the crash log may appear

Comment: I’m using logcat in the CLI. There are several references to a dead object. Do you mean that?

Comment: @LenaBru - attached it to the Android Studio logcat. Nope, no errors in the dead process. I do get: 2020-02-13 21:02:10.453 1160-1160/com.example_androidrn I/Choreographer: Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. maybe 15 seconds before the crash